# why my sql query drops the title of column in associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have two tables: `users` and `scripts`.user hasthe column `user_id` and scripts has two :`script_id` and `cron_formtat`. when i query for the users:

```
$query = "select `user_id` from users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    array_push($usersArr,$row);
}
```

result:

```
[{"user_id":"1"},{"user_id":"2"},{"user_id":"3"},{"user_id":"4"},{"user_id":"5"}]
```

i get associative array (with the title of the column) as i need, but why does my second query returns array with all values but drops the titles of the columns?:

```
$query = "select script_id,`cron_format`  from scripts";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

while($script = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($usersArr as $user){
        $userScriptCronArr[$user["user_id"]][$script["script_id"]] = $script["cron_format"];
    }
}
```

result:

```
{"1":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"},"2":{"1":"*\/3 * * * *","2":"*\/6 * * * *","3":"*\/3 * * * *","4":"* * * * *"},"3" ...
```

in second result the first number is user_id, and for each user im assign's each of the existing scripts.
why does my second query drops the user_id,script_id and cron_format titles?

Comment: Try `foreach($usersArr as $key => $user) {}`, then use `$key` where you like.

Comment: Which variable have the data you are showing us?  Because if you showed us `$userScriptCronArr` then everything is ok... You have keys with data you are searching for inside - 1st key is userID, second is scriptID and values are cron_formats....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong here. You get your associative array.. It's $script

```
while($script = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($usersArr as $user){
       $userScriptCronArr[$user["user_id"]][$script["script_id"]] =    $script["cron_format"];
   }
  }
```

So there is nothing wrong with your query. $userScriptCronArr is constructed as a multidimensional array with two numeric keys.

---

Regarding the angular part:

```
while($script = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($usersArr as $user){
       $userScriptCronArr[] = array(
           "user_id" => $user["user_id"], 
           "script_id" => $script["script_id"], 
           "cron_format" => $script["cron_format"]
       );
   }
}
```

This should yield you an JSON array you can use with your angular code. But please, read the manuals!

Comment: but why am in not seeing the titles of the columns before each var in the array? i used this titles to loop threw the array                 `<tr ng-repeat="x in data | filter: user | filter: script">
                    <td>{{x.user_id}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.script_id}}</td>` and this loop doesnt work...

Comment: Because you add only (!) the value to your new array. $script is associative, so you can access it using the keys "script_id" and "cron_format". Then you instruct PHP to get the value of $script["cron_format"] and put it into your new array $userScriptCronArr. So you take the value out, and put it into a new array. You don't do anything with the key and that's the reason it is lost. I suggest reading the PHP manual about arrays. It is pretty extensive.

Answer (score 0):

In the first output you are pushing the entire query result as it is. But in the second you are not pushing the entire result but initiating the $userScriptCronArr in a numeric array. The data you want is still in the $script. You just have to initialize it properly and you are done.

Comment: i tried to use array_push like this:        `array_push( $userScriptCronArr[$user["user_id"]][$script["script_id"]] , $script["cron_format"]);`...but im getting error saying parameter 1 needs to be an array...do you know how can i use array_push to make userScriptCronArr associative?